# i want to access private method using Class and Method class.can any one explain me what is the error in this code?

Tags: java, reflection

```
//PrivateMethod.java

class PrivateMethod
{
   private void printMessage()
   {
      System.out.println("hello rakesh:");
   }
}

//AccessPrivate.java

import java.lang.reflect.*;
class AccessPrivate
{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
   {
      Class c=Class.forName("PrivateMethod");
      Object o=c.newInstance();
      Method m=c.getDeclaredMethod("printMessage",null);
      m.setAccessible(true);
      m.invoke(o,null);
   }
}
```

Comment: What error are you talking about?

Comment: this code is giving error.can you explain why?

Comment: WHAT error is it giving?

Comment: When you are saying its giving error you should mention the error that you are getting and from which line you are getting

Comment: But please don't do this as a matter of habit: marking things `private` signals to a developer that they can do what they want with that function. Reflection circumvents that, making code difficult to maintain.

Comment: i ran you code and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code(I tested it on jdk 1.7 from cmd):

```
Class<?> c=Class.forName("PrivateMethod");        
Object o=c.newInstance();
Method m=c.getDeclaredMethod("printMessage");
m.setAccessible(true);
m.invoke(o);
```